# Django - How to force server time on DateTimeField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a datetime field on a model

```
date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Also, when i create instance of a model,

```
MyModel.object.create(...)
```

date_added set to local time and not server time.

I need it to be as server time, the problem is when i change local time on pc the field created with the modified time and date.

Is it because my server is local (for dev) or is it how datetimefield field works?

Thanks!

Comment: `auto_now_add` works using `timezone.now()`. It always in UTC.

Comment: See: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py at line: `1543`